# Lua - How do I dynamically call a module?

Tags: oop, module, lua

Here's some much-simiplified Lua code I'm working with.  I need to know how to dynamically call another module ('zebra'):

```
avar = require "avar"
bvar = require "bvar"

function create(zebra)
  print(zebra.new())
end

print(create(avar))
```

And here are two modules:

```
local Avar = {}

function Avar.new()
  return "avar"
end

return Avar

local Bvar = {}

function Bvar.new()
  return "new"
end

function Bvar.old()
  return "old"
end

return Bvar
```

If I try to pass in the string "avar" to my 'create' function, it doesn't work.  If I pass in the word 'avar' with no quotes, it does work, however, I don't understand what avar with no quotes is?  It seems to be a blank table?  Not sure how to pass a blank table as an argument in my main program.

But maybe I'm totally on the wrong path.  How do I dynamically call modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can require any time:

```
function create(zebraModuleName)
  zebraType = require(zebraModuleName)
  print(zebraType .new())
end

print(create("avar"))
print(create("bvar"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`avar` without the quotes is a global variable you created. It is initialized to the value returned by the `require` function<sup>1</sup>, which is the value returned by the module you are invoking. In this case, its a table with the `new` field that happens to be a function.

<sup>1</sup> Importing a modules in Lua is done via regular functions instead of a special syntax. The function call parenthesis can be ommited because parens are optional if you write a function call with a single argument and that argument is a string or a table.

Other than that, there are also some other things you are confusing here:

- The table you are storing on `avar` is not empty! You can print its contents by doing  `for k,v in pairs(avar) do print(k,v) end` to see that.
- The `avar`, `bvar` and `create` variables are global by default and will be seen by other modules. Most of the time you would rather make them local instead.

  ```
  local avar = -- ...
  local bvar = -- ...

  local function create (zebra)
    -- ...
  end
  ```
- The create function clearly expects a table since it does table indexing on its argument (getting the `new` key and calling it). The string doesn't have a "new" key so it won't work.
- You aren't really dynamically calling a module. You are requiring that module in a regular way and it just happens that you pass the module return value into a function.
- `create` always returns `nil` so there is no point in doing `print(create(avar))`. You probablu want to modify `create` to return its object instead of printing it.

Comment: Thank you for all of that.  I took this piece of code out of an entire program where most function are not in the global namespace.  But, yet I think all of my modules are NOT local (per your point 2). Questions:  How to make modules local?  Should I pass in avar with no quotes then?  Per point 4, should I require dynamically?  I'm only alternating between 1 of 3 modules, so I could require them all but just want to do what is right.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kelly: Try to read the Lua code instead of blindly guessing what to do. There is no such thing as a local module - the thing that can be local or global is the value you assign the module table to. (In this case , `local avar = ` vs `avar =`). As for choosing what module to use, you can either load all modules and choose one of the values with if-else-if or a hash table or you could pass a variable with the module name to require instead of passing it a literal string. Requiring everything is simpler though so I would do that unless it turns out to be a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard `require` from lua language or build your own loader using metatables/metamethods.

**1. create a global function:**

```
function dynrequire (module)                                                                                           
  return setmetatable ({},{
    __index = function (table,key)
      return require(module..'.'..key)
    end
  })
end
```

**2. Create your project tree visible to package.path**

```
./MySwiss/
  \___ init.lua
  \___ cut.lua
  \___ glue.lua
  \___ dosomething.lua
```

**3. Make your module dynamic**
you only need to put this line on your `MySwiss/init.lua` (as if you were namespacing a PHP class):

```
return dynrequire('MySwiss')
```

**4. Require your module and use subproperties dynamically**
On your script you only need to require MySwiss, and the folder file (or subfolders with `dynrequire('MySwiss.SubFolderName')`.

```
var X = require('MySwiss')
X.glue()
```

Note that MySwiss doesn't have glue key. But when you try access de glue key the metamethod __index try to require submodule. You can the full project tree using this technique. The only downside is the external dependencies not packed this way.